# How to get values from properties file in Java by a custom method

Tags: java, string, properties, singleton

I have the following code in which I'm trying to get some value from a properties file.
What I want is to have a getData() method which will receive a String parameter containing the key from the properties file. With the code bellow I always get "null" instead of the value of the specified key. Is there something that I didn't figure out?

```
public class PropertiesManager {

    static private PropertiesManager _instance = null;


    private static Properties props;

    protected PropertiesManager(){
        props = new Properties();
        try{
            props.load(PropertiesManager.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config_keys.properties"));

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error" + e);
        }
    }

    public static PropertiesManager getInstance(){
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new PropertiesManager();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public static String getData(String key){
        if(props != null){
            props.getProperty(key);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(getData(Constants.REG_ADDRESS));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have forgotten to add `return` keyword:

```
 if(props != null){
        return props.getProperty(key);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String getData(String key){
        if(props != null){
            props.getProperty(key);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Should be:

```
public static String getData(String key){
         return  props.getProperty(key);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always returnning `null` from   `getData()` method.So change it

```
    public static String getData(String key){
      if(props != null){
            return props.getProperty(key);
      }
     return null;
   }
```